# jQuery - parseJSON not a function?

Tags: jquery

I'm using Wordpress 3 and jQuery 1.4.2. Firebug tells me $.parseJSON is not a function and I'm stumped as to why.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#subscribe_form_submit').click(function(){

    function updatePage(theResponse, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
        theResponse = $.parseJSON(theResponse);
        console.log(theResponse);

        if(theResponse == "OK!"){
            $('#subscribe').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                $('#subscribe').html("<br /><h3 style=\"text-align:center;border:1px solid #fff;background-color:#d3eefe;padding:8px;\">Thanks!</h3><br /><br />");
                $('#subscribe').fadeIn('slow');
            }); 
        }
        else{
            theResponse = $.parseJSON(theResponse);
            console.log(theResponse);

        }
    }

    var theData = $('#subscribe').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.foo.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_17/custom/subscribe.php?' + theData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: updatePage(),
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log((errorThrown ? errorThrown : xhr.status));  
        }
    })

});
```

});

Comment: Look the API documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/,

Comment: In the second last line there's missing a semicolon. Adding that maybe that solves the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you get that error message, but I don't think that's the real problem.

You are calling the `updatePage` function instead of putting it in the object. Remove the parentheses after the name:

```
success: updatePage,
```

As you are calling the function before you do the AJAX call, and without any parameters, the `theResponse` parameter that you try to parse is undefined.

Also, as you are using the `json` data type in the AJAX call, you don't have to parse the data at all, that is already done when the success callback function is called.

Answer (score 1):

You added `dataType:'json'` in the `$.ajax` call.  This means that jQuery will parse the JSON for you.  Also why do you call `$.parseJSON` twice?

Also, like Dick said you can use the `$.getJSON` shorthand.

```
$.getJSON('http://www.foo.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_17/custom/subscribe.php?' + theData, updatePage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the answer above, you might want to try the [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function, make things easier/shorter.